# Navigation Broken on Android App Using Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am writing my first Android App and have implemented Firebase Auth. My app navigation was working correctly before I added in the Firebase pieces. Now I am not able to get from the Main Activity to my starting Frag (Frag1). I would like to have the app open to Frag1 once the Firebase Auth runs through its process, but I can't get that to work. Here are the main parts of my files:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.richeypro.android.fishpro">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name=".CatchApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"
            tools:replace="android:value" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.richeypro.android.fishpro.databinding.ActivityMainBinding


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        var toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        var fragment = Fragment()
        var ft: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        ft.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
        ft.commit()

        var drawer: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.nav_open_drawer, R.string.nav_close_drawer)
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()
        var navigationView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)


        if(auth!=null && intent!= null){
            createUI()
        }
        else{
            startActivity(Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java))
            this.finish()
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if(auth!=null&& intent!= null){
            createUI()
        }
        else{
            startActivity(Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java))
            this.finish()
        }
    }

    fun createUI(){

        var txtName: TextView = binding.txtName
        var txtEmail: TextView = binding.txtEmail
        var txtPhone: TextView = binding.txtPhone
        var txtProvider: TextView = binding.txtProvider
        var btnLogOut: Button = binding.btnLogOut
        var btnCatchList: Button = binding.btnCatchList
        var profile_image: ImageView = binding.profileImage

        val list = auth?.providerData
        var providerData:String = ""
        list?.let {
            for(provider in list){
                providerData = providerData+ " " +provider.providerId
            }
        }

        auth?.let {
            txtName.text = auth.displayName
            txtEmail.text = auth.email
            txtPhone.text = auth.phoneNumber
            txtProvider.text = providerData
            Glide
                .with(this)
                .load(auth.photoUrl)
                .fitCenter()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.login_background)
                .into(profile_image)
        }

        btnLogOut.setOnClickListener{
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    val intent = Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
//                    this.finish()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Log Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        }

        btnCatchList.setOnClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked FAB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val navController: NavController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
            val action = CatchDetailFragmentDirections.actionCatchDetailFragmentToAddCatchFragment(
                null.toString(), 1)
            navController.navigateUp()
            navController.navigate(action)
        }

    }

//    fun generateFBKey(){
//        try {
//            val info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
//                "com.example.firebaseintro",
//                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES
//            )
//            for (signature in info.signatures) {
//                val md: MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
//                md.update(signature.toByteArray())
//                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT))
//            }
//        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
//        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
//        }
//    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        finishAffinity()
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        var id: Int = item.itemId
        var fragment: Fragment
        var intent: Intent = Intent()

        when (id) {
            R.id.nav_catch_list -> fragment = CatchListFragment()
            R.id.nav_add_angler -> fragment = AddAnglerFragment()
            //R.id.nav_help -> //Do something here
            //R.id.nav_feedback -> fragment = SendFeedbackFragment()
            else -> fragment = SelectScreenFragment()
        }

        if (fragment != null) {

            var ft: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            ft.commit()
        } else startActivity(intent)

        var drawer: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.kt

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI
import com.firebase.ui.auth.ErrorCodes
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        private const val RC_SIGN_IN = 123
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        createSignInIntent()

    }




    private fun createSignInIntent() {
        val providers = arrayListOf<AuthUI.IdpConfig>(
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
        )
        startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                .setTheme(R.style.MySuperAppTheme)
                .setLogo(R.drawable.fishem_up_logo_final_main_logo_white)
                .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN
        )
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            var response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
                val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
//                val image = user?.photoUrl
//
//                intent.putExtra("USERNAME", user?.displayName)
//                intent.putExtra("USEREMAIL",user?.email)
//                intent.putExtra("USERPHONE",user?.phoneNumber)
//                intent.putExtra("USERPROVIDER",user?.providerId)
//                intent.putExtra("USERIMAGE",user?.photoUrl)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            else{

                if(response == null){
                    finish()
                }
                if (response?.getError()?.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
                    //Show No Internet Notification
                    return
                }

                if(response?.getError()?.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, response?.error?.errorCode.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                    Log.d("ERRORCODE", response?.error?.errorCode.toString())
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/fui_ic_yahoo_24dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtName"
                    android:text="Peter Allen"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
                    style="@style/TextStyle" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
                    style="@style/TextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Email"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtName" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
                    style="@style/TextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Phone Number"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtEmail" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtProvider"
                    style="@style/TextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Provider"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPhone" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCatchList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.522"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtPhone"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnLogOut"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/fui_idp_button_background_email"
                    android:text="Log Out"
                    android:textColor="@color/browser_actions_bg_grey"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.522"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnCatchList" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_nav" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **500** (five hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how you handle your fragment/activity state. You should only check the `currentUser` when necessary, you don't want it to initialize too early.

```
val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

if (auth.currentUser == null) {
   // LoginActivity
} else {

}
```

You might want to check out [AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) so you can listen to authentication changes asynchronously.

Comment: I will definitely look into this! Thanks! I just need to get the Navigation working.